# "'Table' object has no attribute 'id'" on SQLAlchemy relation with two foreign keys on one table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a relationship set up across three separate classes using SQLAlchemy, with an association table for a many-to-many relationship. Minimal example:

```
from sqlalchemy import *    
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import configure_mappers, relationship

Base = declarative_base()

teams_users = Table(
    'teams_users', Base.metadata,
    Column('team_id', ForeignKey('teams.id')),
    Column('user_id', ForeignKey('users.id'))
)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # No autoincrement, since we're using externally-generated UIDs
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    teams = relationship('Team', secondary=teams_users, back_populates="users")    

class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    game_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('games.id'), nullable=False)
    games = relationship("Game", foreign_keys='games.id')
    users = relationship("User", secondary='teams_users', back_populates="teams")

class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'games'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    team1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    team2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    team1 = relationship("Team", back_populates="games", foreign_keys=team1_id, uselist=False)
    tean2 = relationship("Team", back_populates="games", foreign_keys=team2_id, uselist=False)

# done declaring, trigger the error
configure_mappers()
```

Attempting to query any of these relations returns a `'Table' object has no attribute 'id'` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 35, in <module>
    configure_mappers()
  File "/.../sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3033, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/.../sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1832, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/.../sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 183, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/.../sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1655, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/.../sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1680, in _process_dependent_arguments
    setattr(self, attr, attr_value())
  File "/.../sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 281, in __call__
    x = eval(self.arg, globals(), self._dict)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'
```

My goal in constructing it this way is that I could easily check which Teams each User has ever been a part of.

Additionally, `Game` has two foreign keys into `Team` because the use case for this project supports arbitrarily sized teams, but only ever two teams. This allows me to have a result of "team1 won" and immediately have a reference to the winning users for stat tracking and historical reference.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To define the relationship between a game and the two teams that play in it, you need to only give the `games` table foreign keys; a team can play in multiple games, a one-to-many relationship; remove the `games_id` column altogether. The exception you got is a bit of a red herring, but it fails to properly configure the `foreign_keys='games.id'` argument in a relationship that doesn't need that foreign key.

The relationship configuration on the `Team` class is a little tricky here as the `Team.games` attribute would have to relate to either foreign key. This is covered in the documentation under [*Handling Multiple Join Paths*](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths); you were almost there but there is no `uselist` parameter needed here:

```
class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'games'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    team1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    team2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    team1 = relationship("Team", foreign_keys=team1_id)
    team2 = relationship("Team", foreign_keys=team2_id)
```

Note that I omitted the `back_populates` references here, because two relationships updating a single relationship on the other site leads one or the other of the two foreign keys being updated with the other value, leading to a game between the same team on either side!

The inverse relationship attribute, `Team.games`, requires a custom [`primaryjoin`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.primaryjoin) because you are looking for games where either `team1_id` or `team2_id` is the foreign key pointing back. Use the [`foreign()` annotation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.foreign) to help SQLAlchemy determine when to update the relationship (it'll watch for the foreign key changes), and use a `lambda` to defer resolving the columns:

```
class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    # game_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('games.c.id'), nullable=False)
    games = relationship(
        "Game",
        primaryjoin=lambda: or_(
            Team.id == foreign(Game.team1_id),
            Team.id == foreign(Game.team2_id)
        ),
        viewonly=True,
    )
    users = relationship("User", secondary='teams_users', back_populates="teams")
```

You could also make `primaryjoin` a string containing the expression now being executed in a `lambda`, so `'or_(Team.id == foreign(Game.team1_id), Team.id == foreign(Game.team2_id))'`.

Again, no `back_populates`, this type of relationship can't automatically update relationships between loaded objects. If you need to see these relationships reflected before committing, you'll need to issue a session flush. I also added `viewonly=True`, because you can't map mutations to the `Team.games` list to updates in the database (what would adding a new game to the list mean, that this team is team 1 or team 2?).

You may want to add a custom constraint table to ensure that games never take place between the same team on both sides:

```
class Game(Base):
    # ...
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(team1_id != team2_id, name='different_teams'),
    )
```

A quick demonstration of the relationships:

```
from itertools import combinations

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

teams = [Team() for _ in range(3)]
session.add_all(teams)
user = User(id=42, teams=teams)
session.add(user)

games = [Game(team1=t1, team2=t2) for t1, t2 in combinations(teams, 2)]
session.add_all(games)
session.commit()

for team in user.teams:
    print('Team:', team.id, 'games:', [g.id for g in team.games])
for game in session.query(Game):
    print(f'Game {game.id}: team {game.team1.id} vs {game.team2.id}')
```

which outputs:

```
Team: 2 games: [1, 3]
Team: 1 games: [1, 2]
Team: 3 games: [2, 3]
Game 1: team 1 vs 2
Game 2: team 1 vs 3
Game 3: team 2 vs 3
```